# Is there a way to make the flash[:notice] appear above, or before, the flash[:error]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I'd like to be able to display both a flash[:notice] and a flash[:error] on the same action, but I'd like for the :notice to always be displayed above (or before) the error.  Is there a way to do this?

In my controller, I thought I could just code the flash[:error] before the flash[:notice], so that rails will display it correctly, and it does a vast majority of the time.  But every now and then they are randomly switched, and I can't seem to figure out why.  So, how can I ensure that a flash[:notice] is always displayed above an :error ?

Edit: Thanks to Ben's and Ryan's advice, I've now just set up conditionals in my layout/application file.

```
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <div id="flash_notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
    <% end %>

    <% if flash[:error] %>
        <div id="flash_error"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
    <% end %>
```

I'm pretty satisfied with this, but maybe there's an even better way?

Edit #2:  Yes, there is.  Ben added it to his answer below.  Thanks again Mr. Ben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of display simply depends on your view code. If you do this in your controller:

```
flash[:notice] = "Notice me"
flash[:error] = "BAAAAADDDD"
```

And this in your view:

```
<p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
```

the :notice will always appear first.

Try this for a more elegant approach. The order you define in the array is the order they'll appear in:

```
<% [:error, :notice].each do |condition| %>
  <%= "<p class='#{condition.to_s}'>#{flash[condition]}</p>" if flash.has_key?(condition) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I had just been relying on the code I defined in the application layout (code similar to what Ryan Bigg pointed out below).  Didn't know I could specify their order for a specific view like that, in addition to the general code in the app layout.  Thank you again Mr. Ben.

Comment: Edit:  I didn't mean in addition to the general code in the layout/app file.  I had just been using what Ryan Bates's nifty_layout generated.  Instead I've now just defined the flashes as you have above, along with their appropriate CCS id's.  Also, I had to include conditionals for when the flashes are empty.  I added the code to my question in case there's a better way.  Thank you again.

Comment: There's definitely more sophisticated ways of doing it--I just wanted you to get the nut of the idea. I'll add something to my answer to get you started.

Comment: That's much too elegant and clean.  I prefer my code more clunky and cumbersome.  j/p, thank you big time Ben, and I now understand flashes quite a bit better as well, much appreciated.

Comment: `if flash.has_key?(condition)` will not work in Rails 3.1 as [In Rails 3.1, FlashHash is not derived from Hash] (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L73) use `if flash.include?(condition)` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
Always nil your notice and error object.

<% if flash[:notice] %><p><%= flash[:notice] %><% flash[:notice]=nil %></p><% end %>
<% if flash[:error] %><p><%= flash[:error] %><% flash[:error] =nil %></p><% end %>
```

Comment: just curious, why do you always nil the notice and error objects?

Comment: if you not nil the notice and error then if you render to the the another page same notice/error will appear. I went through the same problem so i keep a habit that always nil the notice/error once i show in the view. Cheer's

Comment: that behavior is by design. If you don't want the flash to be passed to the next action, you can use `Flash.now` instead.

Comment: Thank you too Salil.  As JRL pointed out, you can just flash.now[:error] and it will automatically be cleared on the next action.  That's actually what I'm using for this example.

Answer (score 1):

I would make this a comment but it doesn't do multi-lined code snippets very well. They're probably "randomly switched" because you're using it like this:

```
  <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
    <div id='flash_<%= k %>'><%= v %></div>
  <% end %>
```

In 1.8 hash keys are unordered and because `flash` is a `Hash`, you'll get these output in whatever order Ruby feels like at the time. As Ben suggested, putting them in the "correct" order manually would help.

Comment: Someone's a mind reader.  Yeah, thats pretty damn close to the code I was using in my layout/app file.  Thank you too Ryan for the further explanation.  (Side note:  I'm a fan of your blog.)

Comment: Heh not quite a mind reader, just observant of the patterns in Ruby on Rails :). Good to know I've got another fan, too.